Spark Connect 3.5.1 wont start connect server
I have Apache Spark 3.5.1 and I'm trying to start a Spark connect server.
When I run this command:
./sbin/start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1

I get the following message:
    24/06/26 10:02:18 INFO SparkConnectServer: Starting Spark session.
24/06/26 10:02:18 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.5.1
24/06/26 10:02:18 INFO SparkContext: OS info Mac OS X, 14.5, aarch64
24/06/26 10:02:18 INFO SparkContext: Java version 17.0.7
24/06/26 10:02:18 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:414)

I followed all the steps from the official documentation but it seems that script start-connect-server.sh has problems.

I have found out why this is happening.

If you create SPARK_REMOTE env variable before starting the server it will throw this error.
Another tip: Use this address of spark connect server from documentation "sc://localhost" it only worked for me for standalone applications.

